# Prestashop - image path re-construct for external application

Tags: wordpress, prestashop

I'm trying to do a WP plugin that will show PrestaShop products randomly from the whole database and from one specified category.

I need to **re-construct the image path** for a product having the product id only.

I have tried an SQL query but isn't helping me to construct the right path to the right image for the right product.

```
SELECT p.*,  pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, i.`id_image`, il.`legend` FROM [DB_PREFIX]product p
LEFT JOIN `[DB_PREFIX]product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.`id_lang` = [ID_LANG])
LEFT JOIN `[DB_PREFIX]image` i ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND i.`cover` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `[DB_PREFIX]image_lang` il ON (i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = [ID_LANG])
```

The absolute path of the pictures is: website.com/img/p/

then the number in the url gives the path to the picture.

So with **website.com/5-medium_atch/product-name.jpg** the path of the picture is

**website.com/img/p/5/5-medium_atch.jpg**

and for **website.com/145-home_atch/product-name.jpg**  the path is

**website.com/img/p/1/4/5/145-home_atch.jpg**

I'm using the prestashop version 1.5.4.1 and WP 3.5.2

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult for you either you have to add prestashop url rewriting system Link controller of using the web service to do that. As there is two image path generate one is when seo link disable another is when soe link is enable. So it will be better to made a module in prestashop and fire with query string from wp plugin and than show that product.

Comment: @arifurrahman Thanks for info. I thought about this approach but it looks not reliable to me. Too many settings for the user. In the next WP plugin version I will connect to PS DB and let user import desired products as custom post types and make a random display from WP DB. It will reduce the the loading time, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally do that:

Get these from plugin settings:

```
$product_name = $PrestaShopdb->get_var('SQL here');
$store_url
$image_folder

$id_image = $PrestaShopdb->get_var('
        SELECT i.`position` FROM ps_product p
        LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.`id_lang` = '.$language.')
        LEFT JOIN `ps_image` i ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND i.`cover` = 1)
        LEFT JOIN `ps_image_lang` il ON (i.`id_image` = il.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.$language.')
        WHERE p.`active` = 1
        AND p.`id_product` = '.$product_id.''           
        );          

$image_path = $image_folder . "/". $product_id . "/".$id_image."/" . $product_id.$id_image."-" . $image_size."_default.jpg";

if(!url_exists($image_path)){ //check if file exist? Function is below
    $image_path = $image_folder . "/". $product_id ."/" . $product_id."-" . $image_size."_default.jpg";
}else{
    $image_path = $image_path;
}


function url_exists($url) {
    // Version 4.x supported
    $handle   = curl_init($url);
    if (false === $handle)
    {
        return false;
    }
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);  // this works
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    $connectable = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);    
    return $connectable;
}
```

It looks more like a temporary solution to my question but do the job for now.

Comment: this means that you will check the image folder name and than build.If language and seo url is enable how you manage that. You can use web service or via rss to get product information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to find image folder path in prestashop

```
$oImage = new Image($iImg_id);
$sPath = _PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_.$oImage->getExistingImgPath().'.'.$oImage->image_format;
```